# SQL : Filter the newly added elements on existing ones

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Model` containing `Property`es.

So, I have a table `Models`, a Table `Properties`, and a table `ModelProperties` (ModelId, PropertyId, Value)

Actually when some new `Property` is/are added (in table `Properties`), I would like to update the `ModelProperties` table as well to **add the newly added *Properties* to each of existing *Models***.

See [the SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/942ad/1/0)

Should be careful cause some of the newly created Models could already have the new properties, so in order to update properly I need for each of the existing Model to

1. Select all new Properties to add to that Model (`PropertyId` exist in in `Properties` but not in `ModelProperties` for that `ModelId`)
2. Add to the Model the new Properties it does not have (with empty values).

**Example:**
I have Model `1` and Model `2` with properties till 100. Two new properties were added: `101` and `102`. Model `2` was updated to the property `101`, but not yet `102`. My selection should give/update. My sql should give me the models/properties to update:

```
ModelIdToUpdate PropertyIdToAdd

1               101
1               102

2               102
```

**Q:** What should be the sql script to give the result above?

SQL

````sql
CREATE TABLE "Models" (
  "Id" int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
CREATE TABLE "Properties" (
  "Id" int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
CREATE TABLE "ModelProperties" (
  "ModelId" int NOT NULL,
  "PropertyId" int NOT NULL,
  "Value" int NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("ModelId", "PropertyId")
);

INSERT INTO "Models"     ("Id") VALUES (1), (2);    
INSERT INTO "Properties" ("Id") VALUES (99), (100); -- existing    
INSERT INTO "Properties" ("Id") VALUES (101), (102); -- new
  
INSERT INTO "ModelProperties" ("ModelId", "PropertyId") VALUES
  (1, 99), (1, 100),
  (2, 99), (2, 100), (2, 101); -- Model 2 updated to 101```
````

the select

```
select * from Properties p
left join ModelProperties mp on 
mp.PropertyId = p.Id
where mp.PropertyId is NULL
```

Comment: The SQL fiddle doesn't load for me. If you are including DDL and DML it should be in the question as well; a fiddle should *compliment* the post not be required.

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server? T-SQL doesn't use backticks (`\``) for delimit identifying (it uses ANSI double quotes (`"`) and brackets (`[]`)), `int` does *not* have a precision, and `unsigned` is not a valid property for `int` either.

Comment: Yes, it does matter, if you are using SQL Server then provide valid T-SQL; the above is not valid T-SQL, it does not work: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ac1993d24cbfdd737df7708e737b461). If you are using MySQL then tag [[tag:mysql]]... Tagging [[tag:sql-server]] when you are asking about MySQL is like tagging VB.Net when asking about Java.

Comment: @Larnu updated fiddle, link and the code in OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `CROSS JOIN` your models and your properties, you can then use `NOT EXISTS` to remove those that have a record in your `ModelProperties` table, then use this as the basis for inserting your empty properties:

```
INSERT INTO ModelProperties (ModelId, PropertyId)
SELECT  m.Id,
        p.Id
FROM    Properties p
        CROSS JOIN Models AS m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    ModelProperties AS mp 
            WHERE   mp.ModelId = m.Id 
            AND     mp.PropertyId = p.Id
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93da98/1)**